# Vaadin23 route navigation with parameters

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I have the following route:

```
@Route(value = "jobs/:jobId", layout = JobsLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class ViewJob extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver, HasUrlParameter<String> {
```

When I access the application by the following url:

```
/jobs/456/test
```

I correctly enters ViewJob view.

Now, I'd like to programmatically move to this view from another Vaadin view. For this, I'm trying to do the following:

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate(ViewJob.class, "456/test");
```

but the application fails with the following exception:

```
com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException: No route found for the given navigation target 'com.example.ui.views.job.view.ViewJob' and parameters '{___url_parameter=456/test}'
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.RouteConfiguration.getUrl(RouteConfiguration.java:515)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.navigate(UI.java:914)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to correctly navigate to the `ViewJob` view?

**UPDATED**

**The goal** - I'm trying to implement the logic similar to StackOverflow - when you access the question page without a slug, for example [Vaadin23 route navigation with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73387221/) you will be automatically redirected to the correct url with slug added - [Vaadin23 route navigation with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73387221/vaadin23-route-navigation-with-parameters)

For that I have the following view:

```
@Route(value = "jobs", layout = JobsLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class AllJobsView extends VerticalLayout implements LocaleChangeObserver, HasUrlParameter<String> {

@Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @OptionalParameter String parameter) {
        try {
            Long jobId = Long.parseLong(parameter);
            Vacancy vacancy = vacancyService.findById(jobId, VaadinUtils.getCurrentLocaleIso6391());

            UI.getCurrent().navigate(ViewJob.class, new RouteParameters(Map.of(ViewJob.JOB_ID_PARAMETER, parameter, HasUrlParameterFormat.PARAMETER_NAME, vacancy.getNameSlug())));
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is `ViewJob` view:

```
@Route(value = "jobs/:jobId", layout = JobsLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class ViewJob extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver, HasUrlParameter<String> {
....
}
```

When I try to access `/jobs` - `AllJobsView` is correctly rendered.
When I try to access `/jobs/507/vacancy5` - `JobView` is correctly rendered

but when I try to access `/jobs/507` the following redirection logic is involed from `AllJobsView.setParameter` method:

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate(ViewJob.class, new RouteParameters(Map.of(ViewJob.JOB_ID_PARAMETER, parameter, HasUrlParameterFormat.PARAMETER_NAME, vacancy.getNameSlug())));
```

After that the user is correctly navigated to `/jobs/507/vacancy5` url but the `JobView` content is not rendered.. only `JobsLayout` part.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined a route parameter in the url (`:jobId`). This has to match with the route parameter given to the URL:

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate(ViewJob.class, new RouteParameter("jobId", "456"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do the following now:  `UI.getCurrent().navigate(ViewJob.class, new RouteParameters("jobId", "507"));` but it still fails with the: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation target 'com.example.ui.views.job.view.ViewJob' requires a parameter.`

Comment: This is expected, because combining Route Parameter with HasUrlParameter is not what you want. 

If you wanna access the jobId inside your class, you can use `BeforeEnterEvent` and call `event.getRouteParameters().get("jobId")`.

Comment: After Vaadin debug, I found that I have to add `HasUrlParameterFormat.PARAMETER_NAME, vacancy.getNameSlug()` to parameters. Now I'm able to redirect to ViewJob but ViewJob is not rendered correctly. I have updated my question with details. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Using `UI::navigate` inside the router lifecycle methods is discouraged, you could try `event::forwardTo` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much ! `event::forwardTo` did the trick !